# Installing .sty packages with Kile

Tags: latex

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop. I tex a lot and I like to use Kile for that. I have installed all the packages that exist on the ubuntu repositories. There are still some packages that I wish to install. I have the required .sty (or .cfg) files for them. How do I go about installing them? I would like to make my installation system-wide.

I have read many many threads regarding this online but nothing seems to work for me! I don't know why. Possibly because I'm just not doing it right. (I'm new to Ubuntu).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to install packages from the repositories or do you want to install your own `.sty` files on the system? Do you want to distribute them or only for a local installation? Please note that installing packages (`.deb`) is something different from "installing" `.sty` files.

Comment: Hi. Specifically, I want to install axodraw4j.sty on my own personal system.

Comment: "nothing seems to work for me!" - What have you tried?

Comment: The OP has not documented what he tried, agreed. But please answer the question. How to install .sty packages with Kile. I'm trying to do this for extarrows.sty and many many other packages. I am googling to no avail. Please let us not have to post separate questions to install each .sty package!

Answer (score 1):

> JaxoDraw-2.0 uses a new LaTeX style file called axodraw4j.sty for its
>   LaTeX exports which is based on J. Vermaseren's original axodraw.sty.
>   The name has been changed to avoid any backward compatibility issues
>   with olddocuments that use the original axodraw.sty.

Documentation of axodraw4j is included in the [distribution tar ball](http://jaxodraw.sourceforge.net/download/axodraw4j.html). The latest version of the docs is always available from the [subversion repository](https://jaxodraw.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jaxodraw/trunk/axodraw4j/).

For detailed instructions, see [Installing axodraw4j.sty](http://jaxodraw.sourceforge.net/UsrGuide/axodraw.html)

<sup>Source:JaxoDraw</sup>